# What is the largest single LEGO piece?

Tags: piece-information, size, records, weight

What is the largest single LEGO piece ever produced? This does not include LEGO affiliates like Duplo.

#### Clarifications

- It must be a purchasable block.
- By largest, I mean largest by Volume/Weight of Plastic

Comment: Does this include special one-off bricks? I have seen some giant things that could be considered "one brick" in the Lego Store at the Mall of America, for example, but they're not things you could ever buy.

Comment: Must be a baseplate.  Waiting for the ?x? count to come in...

Comment: Note that DUPLO isn't really an affiliate of LEGO, DUPLO **is** LEGO.

Comment: By "no affiliate", I think he wanted to exclude things such as playtables or other furniture pieces, which would easily win.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The ["Extra Large" grey baseplate](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/X-Large-Gray-Baseplate-628) is 15"/38cm square, with 48 studs to a side.

Alternatively, the moulded castle baseplate had a greater volume (with height), and a base size of 32x48 studs and 6 bricks high (15"x10"/38x25cm) ([in other colours as well](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/30271)):

[image: Baseplate 32 x 48 x 6 Raised with Corner Pits and River Pattern (30271px1)]

[Tim](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/105/tim) offered up [the following](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/161/563), also with a base size of 32x48 studs, 6 bricks high (15"x10"/38x25cm) (it came in a [few other colours too](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/44510)):

[image: Baseplate 32 x 48 x 6 Raised with Steps and MdBlue/Green Garden Pattern (44510px2)]

Peeron also lists a [48x48 Raised with Staircases and Pits](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/33214):

[image: Baseplate 48 x 48 Raised with Staircases and Pits with Yellow Cobblestone and Ivy Pattern (33214px2)]
[Peeron.com](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/33214px2)

As well as a very old "[Giant Base Plate](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/782)" and a "[Road 3-way Curve with Gray Pattern](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/078-1)", both at 50x50 studs.

Joubarc suggested the ["Boat Hull Floating 74 x 18 x 7"](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/57789):

[image: Boat Hull Floating 74 x 18 x 7 (57789)]
[Peeron.com](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/57789)

Stretching the definition of "Single Piece" somewhat, the "Electric Technic Control Centre with Yellow and Red Buttons" from the Technic Control Center was a beast of a part:

[image: Electric Technic Control Centre with Yellow and Red Buttons (2840c01)]
[Peeron.com](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/2840c01)

---

Made this CW to allow others to add their contenders

Comment: It's still pressed from a single sheet, so the *volume of plastic* is probably less.

Comment: @fredley Techincally I believe they're injection moulded rather than pressed, and the thickness is usually consistent across the part...

Comment: This is getting silly - I need someone to get all these pieces and weigh them, or measure their volume via displacement ;)

Comment: A **LARGE** bounty will be awarded to anyone who does that!

Comment: @Zhaph it's my understanding that baseplates are vacuum-formed. There is a mold involved but the sheet of plastic goes in whole.

Comment: @erikolson Fair enough :) that would have some impact then, and I imagine their automated factories wouldn't leave the plastic heating up long enough to sag into the middle for added thickness on the sides

Answer (score 15):

[image: Plastic Playscape Soccer Field Base 72 x 46 x 7]

this brick has always annoyed me, when sorting my bricks

Comment: ooo, soccer stadium base. nice.

Answer (score 12):

if you're just counting the basal area, it seems to be the [gray 48x48 baseplate](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/X-Large-Gray-Baseplate-628):

[image: gray base plate]

Comment: man, this was a beast of a baseplate. Also game in green as half of the lego football field.

Comment: Before that, the extra-large gray baseplate was 50x50, but nowadays only the 48x48 can be bought.

Comment: Also in Blue, plus some rare ones that were never in sets: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4186

Answer (score 11):

[image]

If you go by Volume/Weight. This is heaviest single-element I've ever seen.  It's not just plastic but it's one element made and sold by LEGO.

Comment: Good call, I didn't think about "multipart" single bricks, although I think I can still trump that one with a different Technic controller hang on...

Comment: I think there's two categories: Single plastic-only piece and Single Lego element.

Comment: There you go, Electric Technic Control Centre with Yellow and Red Buttons ;)

Comment: Yes, and there's one sitting in a box in my loft. Was one of my brother's sets, lucky so and so ;)

Comment: I found this video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJXPkhjGwkg&feature=related) with the Electric Technic Control Centre in use

Answer (score 5):

@Zhaph : 
(from my sister's LEGO collection)
[image: lego fairy castle base]

Comment: What set was this from? Possibly a Belville one?

Comment: @tombull89 Yeah, my sister's: Bellville 5862

Comment: Your sister's, yeah, right :-)

Comment: @Joubarc And we all know how many 'sisters' *you* have.