# What is the biggest base plate available?

Tags: piece-information

I'm looking for as large a base plate as possible. Below is a 48x48 stud base, it's the largest I've seen.

Are larger plates available? Either the thin type (as pictured) or the regular plate thickness will do!

[image: baseplate]

Comment: As  a kid, I remember longer but narrower green, thin plates. The full set included streets. It was midseventies. Of course, I was a kid, it might not have been longer, but it took up a big portion of my room.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The largest baseplate (thin kind) is 50x50 studs: http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=4186a#T=P

The largest regular plate is 16x16 studs only: http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=91405#T=P

Answer (score 10):

The largest official baseplate that I'm aware of is 50x50 modules.

[image: 782]

It's only slightly larger than a 48x48, and it's a bit more difficult to use in large setups since most other common baseplates have side lengths that are a multiple of 16, so you might actually be better off with a 48x48 depending on what you are trying to do.

This part hasn't been available since the 70s, but you can still pick it up [on Bricklink](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=4186a).

You may be interested in this answer which includes other raised baseplates:

[What is the largest single LEGO piece?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-is-the-largest-single-lego-piece)

Answer (score 0):

There is a 48 by 64 Lego-compatible baseplate available.

Comment: From whom? How do you know this?