# What is the longest 1×x brick ever released?

Tags: size, records

Out of curiosity: How long can a 1×x brick be?

When there are differences, I can think of the following categories:

- Longest brick ever included in a regular Lego set
- Longest brick ever available through other channels
- Longest brick produced ever and visible on exhibits or other occasions, but unavailable to the public

EDIT: I am only interested in bricks made by LEGO, clone brands do not count.

Comment: Within bricks, do you include plates and tiles?

Comment: No, this is another question to be asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean specifically Lego bricks, I'm pretty sure the 1x16 was/is the longest one made. Outside of the 1x? sized bricks, the longest plain shaped brick that I know of is part #30072 or #47122 at 24 studs long.  I don't know about other brands though.

Interesting related post:
[What is the largest single LEGO piece?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-is-the-largest-single-lego-piece)

Comment: Yes, I mean LEGO specifically, I'll add this to my question.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't say anything about **modified** 1 x bricks.

- This is **Item 47978** and it is actually listed as a **2x24** brick, because of the added bit in the middle.

[image]

Comment: Ah, sneaky sneaky! ;)

Comment: Still technically a 2x though :P

Answer (score 5):

This technic rack is 1x20 and is exactly 1 wide, no hanging out bits

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2428#T=C

Comment: Ah, nice find!  I wouldn't consider it a brick though being only 2/3 the height.

Comment: And no studs, unfortunately. +1 for this nice find, anyway.