# What are the longest 1×x and 2×x plates and tiles ever released?

Tags: bricks-and-pieces, records

As a follow up of [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/11512/what-is-the-longest-1%C3%97x-brick-ever-released), here is the question for plates and tiles. What are the longest 1×x  and 2×x plates and tiles ever released by Lego?

When there are differences, I can think of the following categories:

- Longest brick ever included in a regular Lego set
- Longest brick ever available through other channels
- Longest brick produced ever and visible on exhibits or other occasions, but unavailable to the public

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's going to be the 1x12 (#60479) and 2x16 (#4282) for regular Lego plates. The next longest plain-ish plate is probably the 6x28 (#5301, 5309, 4093), but these are thicker than typical plates.

For regular tiles I think the 1x8 (#4162) and 2x4 (#87079) are the longest. Outside of the 2x? they made some odd-ball Scala tiles at 3x6 (#6934) and 8 x 20 x 2/3 (#6923). Then there's the big 8x16 (#48288, 90498).

Does Modulex count since it's a Lego company product? There were Modulex 1x16 (MX1616M) plates and 2x12 (Mx1012) tiles. They also made a huge 22x60 (Mx2420D) plate according to Bricklink. Of course these pieces are only longer in terms of studs, because of the smaller scale, the Modulex bricks are not longer in millimeters/inches.  I'm curious if anyone has one of the 22x60 plates on hand to verify the bottom type?  Then of course there are baseplates, I guess I assumed you weren't referring to those.

Comment: Yes, Modulex counts, but it is good that it is placed in a category of its own.

Comment: Looking at mine, Modulex 1×16 a fraction smaller than system 1×10, as I can feel the step. So not the longest. Would have thought should be =, why not?

Answer (score 5):

There is news (postdating the accepted answer): There are now tiles 2x6 (#69729) from LEGO available, e.g., in some Nintendo Super Mario sets.

Answer (score -2):

2×16 from Guarded Inn 6067 (=10000). The floor uses a wider plate & this together.